# ¿Es normal que php tome tanto tiempo para la transaccion de volumenes grande de registros?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Tengo una funcion donde guardo a mysql con laravel alrededor de entre 6500 y 7000
registros a la base de datos por ende son esa cantidad de iteracion se demora al rededor de 15 minutos lo que encuentro es mucho,

se que depende mucho de como este escrito el codigo para el performance pero de todas maneras pido la aclaracion de los entendido

¿existe alguna manera de quee tome menos tiempo?

[Subo mi codigo]

```
foreach ($detallado as $value => $d) {
            try {

                if (! empty($d['IdUnidadRecaudadora'])) {
                    $tratamiento = Helpers::BuscaOrdenArchivo($idtiporecaudacion);
                    $posmonto = $tratamiento['monto'];
                    if ($tratamiento['dv'] == "-") {
                        $rutpos = $tratamiento['rut'];
                        $rut = $d[$rutpos];
                    } else {
                        $posrut = $tratamiento['rut'];
                        $posdv = $tratamiento['dv'];
                        $rut = trim($d[$posrut]).trim($d[$posdv]);
                    }
                    if ($idtiporecaudacion == 10) {
                        $rut = $d[$tratamiento['rut']];
                        $rutcompleto = Helpers::SeparaRut(trim($rut));
                        $rut = $rutcompleto[0];
                        $Dv = $rutcompleto[1];
                        $monto = trim(str_replace('V', '', $d[$posmonto]));
                    } else {
                        $rutcompleto = Helpers::SeparaRut($rut);
                        $rut = $rutcompleto[0];
                        $Dv = $rutcompleto[1];
                        $monto = $d[$posmonto];
                    }
                    $contribuyente = Contribuyente::where([
                        ['Rut', '=', $rut],
                        ['Dv', '=', $Dv],
                    ])->get()->toarray();
                    if (!empty($contribuyente[0]['IdContribuyente'])) {
                        //Si existe entonces busca compromiso de pago
                        $compromisopago = CompromisoPago::with('mandato')->where([
                            ['C_IdContribuyente', '=', $contribuyente[0]['IdContribuyente']],
                            ['UR_IdUnidadRecaudadora', '=', $d['IdUnidadRecaudadora']],
                            ['Estatus', '=', 1],
                        ])->first();

                        if (!empty($compromisopago->mandato->Folio)) {
                            // Si no esta vacio el folio lo asigna a la variable
                            $folio = $compromisopago->mandato->Folio;
                            if (empty($compromisopago->IdCompromisoPago)) {
                                // entra si no existe compromiso de pago
                                $logs = new Logs();
                                $logs->Mensaje = 'no se encuentra compromiso de pago';
                                $logs->Accion = 'Buscar id del compromiso de pago';
                                $logs->Variable1 = 'Id del contribuyente: '.$contribuyente[0]['IdContribuyente'];
                                $logs->Variable2 = ' no se encuentra comnpromiso de pago pero aun asi se guarda el detalle fecha: '.$fechaestadistica;
                                $logs->save();
                                $idcompromisopago = 1;

                            } else {
                                //existe compromiso de pago por lo que lo asigna a una variable
                                $idcompromisopago = $compromisopago->IdCompromisoPago;
                            }
                        } else {
                            //  guardar en tabla logs no existe mandato
                            $logs = new Logs();
                            $logs->Mensaje = 'no se encuentra mandato(Folio)';
                            $logs->Accion = 'Buscar mandato(Folio)';
                            $logs->Variable1 = 'Rut del contribuyente:'.$contribuyente[0]['Rut'].'-'.$contribuyente[0]['Dv'].' e id de la UR: '.$d['IdUnidadRecaudadora'];
                            $logs->Variable2 = 'Con fecha de subida '.$fechaestadistica;
                            $logs->save();
                        }
                    } else {
                        //  guardar en tabla logs no existe contribuyente pero igual se guarda el detalle perro papurri papa
                        $logs = new Logs();
                        $logs->Mensaje = 'no se encuentra Contribuyente';
                        $logs->Accion = 'Buscar id del contribuyente Rut '.$rut.' dv '.$Dv;
                        $logs->Variable1 = 'id tipo recaudación '.$idtiporecaudacion;
                        $logs->Variable2 = ' no se encuentra contribuyente pero aun asi se guarda el detalle fecha: '.$fechaestadistica;
                        $logs->save();
                    }
                }       

                $detalle = new Pago();              
                $detalle->CP_IdCompromisoPago = $idcompromisopago;
                $detalle->NroComprobante = $folio;
                $detalle->MontoPagado = $monto; //monto pagado
                $detalle->FechaPago = $fechacontable;
                $detalle->MesPago = substr($fechaestadistica, 5, 2);
                $detalle->save();
                unset($detallado[$value]);


            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                dd($e->getMessage(), $e->getLine(), $d);
            }
```

Comment: según tengo entendido, no debería tomar ni un minuto, siempre y cuando esos 7k registros estén listos, quizás la generación de los registros es lo que esta tomando demasiado tiempo

Comment: no deberia de tardar tanto, seria bueno revisar tu consulta, la estructura de la y las tablas, si te hacen faltan indices, etc...

Comment: si quieres ayuda mas concreta deberías considerar poner un poco de tu código para verificar si tienes código que genera mala performance

Comment: @jorgemarquez Estimado la verdad es que lo registros vienen listos y la insercion se hace en una sola tabla y en caso de que falte algo en una tabla logs

Comment: Voy a subir mi codigo

Answer (score -3):

Prueba a hacerlo en una transacción de mysql, en pruebas que he realizado la velocidad se incrementa en varios ordenes de magnitud.
http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.transactions.php

```
DB::beginTransaction();

[your code]

DB::commit();
```

Comment: Estimado no me ayuda mucho su respuesta ya que es vaga

Comment: Revisa [answer] pues esto es más un comentario que respuesta

Comment: Además que las respuestas que son solo enlaces se consideran de baja calidad

Comment: No entiendo por que se me vota negativo, cuando publico la pregunta no incluyo ningún tipo de código fuente para responder, simplemente le comente que metiera su proceso en una transacción de mysql, para que pudiera ver si incrementaba la velocidad.